# Django Server timed out when working with theano

Tags: python, django

I want to deploy a django-based website for scientific calculation using theano. But only one line

```
import theano
```

makes the server timed out. The server used Apache2 and mod_wsgi.

And it works fine if I deleted the line importing theano. I wonder what the reasons are.

By the way, if I test the website locally by simply running

```
manage.py runserver
```

It works fine even importing the theano lib.

Please anybody knows the reasons? :(

(The environment is ubuntu-server 12.04 LTS)

Here is the error.log of apache:

```
[Mon Apr 15 21:53:50 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.2+.
[Mon Apr 15 21:53:50 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.
[Mon Apr 15 21:53:50 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.6.17 PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1 mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: could you post your exact error as it appears in apache error log?

Comment: have you check the memory usage?

Comment: More than half of the memory is not used.

Answer (score 0):

Usually due to what is described in:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API